# Why doesn't Apple Mail let me move a message when viewing it in a Smart Mailbox?

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, mail-rules

I use Apple Mail as an IMAP client for my Gmail account. I have a few Smart Mailboxes that I use regularly, e.g. "Today", "Yesterday", etc.

If I'm browsing the contents of a smart mailbox and mark a message read / unread or delete it, the change is immediately visible in the smart mailbox and also in the original folder.

But if I try to move a message to a folder while browsing in a smart mailbox, it has no effect. The message briefly disappears from the smart mailbox, and then immediately reappears. It remains in the original folder, as if the move had no effect.

I thought this was just an unfortunate limitation of smart mailboxes, but then I found this quote in [Apple help](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/use-smart-mailboxes-mlhlp1190/mac):

> If you change an email while viewing it in a Smart Mailbox—such as marking the email as read or unread, or **moving** or deleting it—the change is reflected in the mailbox where the email is stored.

So what's going on? Is there a setting I need to adjust to get this to work? Is it a limitation of using Apple with Gmail / GSuite accounts?

Or, is there a workaround for this? Some way to jump to a message in its original folder, so I can move it from there?

[image]

Comment: A smart mailbox isn't really a mailbox and doesn't contain anything. It's a saved Spotlight search. You can't change the results of the search without changing the search criteria.

Comment: Understood. But note the quote above from Apple help.

Comment: I'm not trying to move something "out" of the smart mailbox. The smart mailbox has identified a message and I want to move that original message to a new location. It then may or may not fall into the smart mailbox criteria.

Comment: I can move messages when I manually type search criteria into the search bar. Based on what Apple said above, the same concept should work for smart mailboxes.

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong. Um. It could be a limitation or issue specific to your setup or configuration although I'm unsure where to look at. Tough question.

Comment: I can't reproduce behaviour in 3rd paragraph. Yes, the message briefly disappears from the Smart Folder, but then it reappears with its location being the destination of the move. My only question: Is the source or destination one of the special gmail folders - like Archive?

Comment: The smart mailbox, in this case, has two criteria: "Message is in Mailbox 'All Inboxes' " and "Date received is today". When I move a message from the smart folder, it disappears, then reappears. I did notice that the message is visible in the destination folder, but it's still present in the inbox, so it still qualifies for the Smart Mailbox and is still present in the actual inbox. It's like Apple Mail is labeling the message, but not moving it out of the inbox.

Comment: For this mail account (actually, for all Gmail accounts I'm using in Apple Mail), the "Archive Mailbox" in Preferences | Accounts | Mailbox Behaviors is set to "[Gmail]/All Mail".

Comment: From your comment, you said that it the message is “visible in the destination folder, but still present in the inbox.”  Is the destination folder on the server or local to your machine?

Comment: @Allan On the server

Comment: It's like Apple Mail is failing to remove the "Inbox" label from the message in Gmail.

Comment: I suspect that moving a message in a smart mailbox actually copies it rather than moving it. That's why you see it in both the inbox and the destination folder.

Comment: I have created a Smart Mailbox exactly like yours. It behaves as you expect when moving messages. Possible differences: I don't synchronise the Google Archive folder/label; I am running macOS 14.0.

Comment: @Gilby Huh, interesting! I'm also on macOS 14.0 (though this has been a problem for a year or two). What do you mean about synchronizing the Archive label?

Comment: @Gilby Do you mind sharing an image of your smart mailbox settings?

Comment: As another data point: Just in case there was something funky about my Mac user or my Gmail account, I created a new Mac user and set up Mail there with a separate Gmail account. I still had the same behavior: the message would briefly disappear from the smart mailbox, then reappear. It was tagged with the destination label but never removed from the inbox.

Comment: Re Archive label: Syncing of this label (and others) is controlled by settings on the gmail server. I think we are gong to need to see your gmail settings, particularly labels, inbox and imap.  My smart mailbox is identical with yours.

Comment: @Gilby So you're saying that in your Gmail settings, you have "Show in IMAP" unchecked for "All Mail"?

Comment: @Gilby That fixed it! In Gmail settings, I turned off "Show in IMAP" for "All Mail" then I restarted Apple Mail. I can't believe it, but now my smart mailboxes are working as expected. Thanks! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it and award you the bounty.

Comment: Glad you got there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer, "Gmail" refers to what is visible in the Google Mail web interface and directly relates to the what is stored on Google's servers.

The Gmail product has concepts which do not fully match the usual IMAP protocol. This causes considerable confusion when an IMAP client (e.g. Apple Mail) does not show a mail folder structure in quite the same way as the Gmail web interface.

Some problem areas:

- **Categories** (e.g. Social) which are a message tag and have no equivalent in IMAP. These can be ignored as far as Apple Mail is concerned.
- **Labels** which can be applied to messages and any message can have multiple labels.
- GMail does not have **Folders** which are a core concept in structuring email in any IMAP client.

This mismatch between label and folder concepts has to be resolved by each IMAP client.

In Apple Mail, GMail's labels are two-way synchronised with Apple Mail's folders. But messages can have more than one label with the consequence that messages can appear in more than one folder. This can be something of a surprise and, worse, can cause unexpected behaviour.

The unexpected behaviours are often a result of which Gmail **System labels** are synchronised to Apple Mail folders.

Based on my experience the synchronisation of System labels should be reduced to the essentials. My Gmail web settings for System labels to/from IMAP are reduced to this:

[image]

Notice that IMAP synchronisation of the **All Mail** label is disabled.

If an "all mail" folder is wanted, it is best to create a Smart Folder in Apple Mail, like this:

[image]

So, in simple terms, disable IMAP synchronisation of "All Mail".

Comment: This solved it for me - I had to uncheck "Show in IMAP" for "All Mail" and then restart Apple Mail. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

A Smart Mailbox isn't a mailbox to store emails, it's designed to ***sort*** your emails for you to have all emails of a certain kind in the same mailbox. You can also observe that a Smart Mailbox can take emails from all of your inboxes, even across accounts:

[image: Screenshot of two emails from two different accounts in a Smart Mailbox]

---

Due to this, emails of a specific kind (e.x. Received today) will stay in the Smart Mailbox even if they are moved (except if they get deleted).

Let's use a simple example if that's still unclear:

- You have received an email at 8am this morning.
- You have a Smart Mailbox configured to show email received today.

This email will be in one of your main inboxes (consider there are no rules applied) **and** in the Smart Mailbox (received today).

Even if you move the email to another mailbox, the email will still keep its "Received at 8am" attribute and it will therefore still stay in the Smart Mailbox.

---

#### Solution

What you need to do to be able to move items out of the Smart Mailbox to another mailbox is make a Smart Mailbox (or edit yours) and set it to something similar to this:

[image]

Here, it's a sample Smart Mailbox that should show all emails received today. **But**, it will exclude messages that lend in the "Newsletters" folder. This means that if you move a message to this folder, the email will disappear from the Smart Mailbox, even if it was received today.

You'll just have to add a condition for each of your mailboxes.

Comment: Thanks - I understand how a smart mailbox works. I just added a photo of the definition ("date is today" and "in All Inboxes"). When I'm browsing the contents of this smart mailbox and I drag a message into a folder (a non-inbox folder), then according to the excerpt from Apple's docs, the message will be moved into the target folder and out of the inbox, so it should no longer satisfy the criteria of my "Today" smart mailbox.

Comment: But what actually happens is that it gets labeled with the new folder, but is still in the inbox. This only happens when a smart mailbox is involved - if I drag an email out of the inbox and into another folder, it works correctly.

Comment: The question isn't why the message is still in the smart mailbox. The question is about why it's still in the Inbox after being moved to another folder.

Comment: @Barmar I think I have answered that: "This email will be in one of your main inboxes (consider there are no rules applied) and in the Smart Mailbox (received today).

Even if you move the email to another mailbox, the email will still keep its "Received at 8am" attribute and it will therefore still stay in the Smart Mailbox." See the full example for more info

Comment: That's NOT what they're complaining about. They're complaining that it's still in the Inbox, not the mailbox they moved it to. The received time is irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar Oh. Okay, I've misunderstood the question then.

Comment: @Bill - You wouldn't also be using Mail *Rules* in addition to the Smart Mailboxes, would you?  Even so, this sounds like a bug with Smart Mailbox feature Apple shoud address.

Comment: @Allan No, I don't have any Mail Rules defined.